# perl equivalent of sh -e

Tags: linux, perl, shell-scripting

In `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` (and I guess a lot of other shells), starting scripts with `#!/bin/sh -e` (or executing `set -e` in someplace in the script) would cause the script to abort when any command line inside the script exits with a status code different than 0.

Is there any equivalent or workaround to get the same behavior in a perl script? (i.e. if any instruction generates an error or if any external command executed with `system(...)` or backticks returns error code then exit immediately)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.0/autodie.html) core module. This replaces calls like `open` and `fork` with functions that die on failure. To get it to work with `system`, you need to import `:all` or `:system`, since the default does not do so.

```
use strict;   #always!
use warnings; #always!
use autodie qw(:system);

system('/bin/false'); #This will die
print "This will never be printed\n";
```

It's important to note that for `autodie` to work with `system`, you need the `IPC::System::Simple` module. Install it with CPAN, or on Ubuntu you can `sudo apt-get install libipc-system-simple-perl`.